# How to hide submenu on click event

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

http://plnkr.co/edit/vmKoBHEKq0wP3du7gtps?p=preview

I want to write directive for hide submenu on click but it is not working properly.

Hover click on menu, Submenu are display but click on submenu I cannot manage hide all submenu

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you really need a directive for doing this. If you don't, you could use simply 'ng-hide' and 'ng-click' directives to make this works.

In the element you want to hide, put `ng-hide="hideSubmenu"` and in the element who will hide it, put a `ng-click="hideSubmenu = true"`.

In your code:

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
      <p>Hello name {{name}}!</p>
      <div>
          <div class="col-md-1" style="padding-left: 00px;padding-right: 350px">
              <div class="cssmenu" ng-hide="hideSubmenu">
               ...
               <li><a href="#/" ng-click="hideSubmenu = true;">Type</a></li>
               <li><a href="#/" ng-click="hideSubmenu = true;">Request</a></li>
               ...
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: according to ur answer On click Submenu hide only one time..after hover click on menu i cant show submenu again this a main paroblem